# How to read contents of csv file uploaded using ngFileUpload?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, csv

I am using ngFileUpload to upload the csv file. Is there a way to read the contents of the file before saving it to db.

```
$scope.uploadFile = function (file) {
$scope.uploadFileProgress =true

    Upload.upload({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'api/contacts/contacts-upload/',
        data: {"upload": file, 'website': $scope.websiteId}
    }).then(function (resp) {

        $scope.uploadFileProgress =false
        $scope.uploadFileSuccess = true
    }, function (resp) {
        console.log('Error status: ' + resp.status);
    }, function (evt) {

    });
};
```

Comment: You won't be able to read the contents on the client side javascript unless you upload in a different way.

Comment: @meyer9  In that case is it possible to download the file once uploaded and read its contents? In the .then(function (resp)) {} after uploading.

Comment: A quick google search provided this: https://github.com/bahaaldine/angular-csv-import. Looks like it works well too, they provide a live demo.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the jquery csv plugin if you can use jquery with this project https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv